# Do SPDR Constituent Stocks Change?

Tags: etf

I know the relative weights will obviously change over time, but I'm trying to find out if the overall constituent stocks change. I assume they do, but I'm not sure where to find out the historical lists.

Comment: SPDR has many different funds, are you talking about SPY?

Comment: @littleadv I'm actually interested in SPY and the other sector funds (XLY, XLB, XLE, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the constituent funds will change as stocks are added or removed from the index that they track.

Note that most stock indexes are *market cap weighted*. The benefit of this weighting scheme is that stocks don't need to be rebalanced to match the index. As stocks go up in value they automatically increase in weight to match the index.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an easy way to find the historical stock listings for the various SPDR ETFs?